# Error in DynamicDestinations: Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm getting an error while executing below code:

```java
tableRows2.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
          .to(new DynamicDestinations<TableRow, TableRow>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
                public TableDestination getTable(TableRow dest) {
                      List<TableRow> list = sideInput(bqDataView);
                      String table = list.get(0).get("table").toString();
                      String tableSpec = "ProjectId:DatasetId."+table;
                      String tableDescription = "";
                      return new TableDestination(tableSpec, tableDescription);
                }

                public String getSideInputs(PCollectionView<List<TableRow>> bqDataView) {
                    String str = bqDataView.toString();
                    return str;
                }

                @Override
                public TableSchema getSchema(TableRow destination) {
                    List<TableRow> list = sideInput(bqDataView);
                    String[] schemas = list.get(0).get("schema").toString().split(",");
                    List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i=0;i<schemas.length;i++)
                    {
                        fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName(schemas[i].split(":")[0]).setType(schemas[i].split(":")[1]));
                    }
                    TableSchema schema = new TableSchema().setFields(fields);
                    return schema;
                }

                @Override
                public TableRow getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow> element) {
                    return null;
                }
              }.getSideInputs(bqDataView)).withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER));
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```java
  (7dc1af5b557d4d6b): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Table reference is not in [project_id]:[dataset_id].[table_id] format: SimplePCollectionView{tag=Tag<org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionViews$SimplePCollectionView.<init>:403#5f2ef1f005ae0b4>}
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers.parseTableSpec(BigQueryHelpers.java:102)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$TableSpecToTableRef.apply(BigQueryHelpers.java:286)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$TableSpecToTableRef.apply(BigQueryHelpers.java:282)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider$NestedValueProvider.get(ValueProvider.java:131)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider$NestedValueProvider.get(ValueProvider.java:131)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider$NestedValueProvider.get(ValueProvider.java:131)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.DynamicDestinationsHelpers$ConstantTableDestinations.getDestination(DynamicDestinationsHelpers.java:64)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.DynamicDestinationsHelpers$ConstantTableDestinations.getDestination(DynamicDestinationsHelpers.java:41)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.PrepareWrite$1.processElement(PrepareWrite.java:58)
```

Is this the right way to implement DynamicDestinations in Apache Beam?
Also, is it always necessary to return String in getSideInputs() method?
What should be written in getDestination() method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are passing side inputs to the `DynamicDestinations` incorrectly. Specifically, since you are calling `getSideInputs` within the call to `to(...)`, you are using the result of `getSideInputs` -- essentially the following:

```java
tableRows2.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
      .to(bqDataView.toString())
```

Looking at the interface for `DynamicDestinations` and the test for BigQueryIO, it seems like you should do something more like the following:

```java
final PCollectionView<List<TableRow>> bqDataView = /* ... */;
tableRows2.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
    .to(new DynamicDestinations<TableRow, TableRow>() {

        // ...

        // Note this method needs to be overridden and use
        // the same signature as in DynamicDestinations. Also,
        // it should not be invoked as part of the apply.
        @Override
        public List<PCollectionView<?>> getSideInputs() {
          return ImmutableList.of(bqDataView);
        }

        // ...
      }).withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER));
```

---

Also, rather than using a `DynamicDestinations<TableRow, TableRow>`, the second type should be something that you can group by to identify the table being written to. In your case it seems like everything is going to the same actual destination, so you could just use a `String` with a fixed value:

```
new DynamicDestinations<TableRow, String>() {
  @Override
  public TableDestination getTable(String unusedDest) {
    // ...
  }

  @Override
  public TableSchema getSchema(String unusedDest) {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public String getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow> element) {
    return "destination";
  }
}
```